# I want to connect my iOS simulator to Ingress-nginx

Tags: react-native, nginx-ingress, skaffold

I am trying to connect my iOS simulator running a React Native application to an Ingress-nginx load balancer running inside skaffold under the domain ticketing.dev. I ran `skaffold dev --port-forward` but it only forwarded the services under the default namespace, not the ingress namespace. I can do it this way but I do not want to connect individually to the respective microservice since that removes the point of the load balancer. How do I connect the simulator to the load balancer?

This is the configuration for my load balancer

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/courses/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: courses-srv
                port:
                  number: 3001
```

This is the configuration for skaffold

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: axis14/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "src/**/*.ts"
            dest: .
    - image: axis14/courses
      context: courses
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "src/**/*.ts"
            dest: .
```